# How to send value from C# to java script on Asp.Net's Button click event?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying fetch c# value in to JavaScript any body can help me to resolve this.

*ASP.NET CODE*

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit"   class="btn btn-success btn-lg" ID="btnsubmit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click"/>
```

*C# code*

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string abc="xyz";
   // From here i need to Call JavaScript Function 
   // suppose code is like myfunction(abc)<-Java script function
   myfunction(abc);
}
```

*Javascript*

```
<script type="javascript/text">

  function myfunction(abc){
    var val = abc
    console.log(val);
    // here i want to get abc value is this possible
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Registers the startup script with the Page object using a type, a key, a script literal.

*Code*

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string abc="xyz";       

      //If the string can contain apostrophes or backslashes, you would need to escape them
      string value = abc.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'");
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","myfunction('" +value + "')",true);
 }
```